# How to return result of MYSQL COUNT(*) Statement into separate columns within a HTML Table

Tags: php, mysql

***How to return result of MYSQL COUNT(*) Statement into separate columns within a HTML Table***

**MYSQL - PHP**

```
$sql= mysql_query("select count(*), shop_order_action from shop_orders o
                  WHERE shop_order_action IN ('Sale', 'Transfer', 'Delivery', 'Return')
                  AND shop_order_day = '28' AND shop_order_month = '08' AND shop_order_year = '2014'
                  AND shop_order_location = 'Bawtry'
                  GROUP BY FIELD (shop_order_action, 'Sale', 'Transfer', 'Delivery', 'Return')");


while ($row=mysql_fetch_row($sql)) {
echo "<pre>";
print_r($row);
echo "</pre>";

}
```

**RESULT OF PRINT_R**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 8
    [1] => Sale
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => Transfer
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => Return
)
```

**TABLE**

```
Shop Action    Count
```

---

```
SALE           <? echo $row[0] ?> 
TRANSFER       <? echo $row[0] ?> 
DELIVERY       <? echo $row[0] ?>            
RETURN         <? echo $row[0] ?>
```

So I need to return the correct row value i.e. Sale, Transfer ... etc in the corresponding column within the table.

I could iterate through the results with a while loop, however, I'm having trouble figuring out how to structure the loop so that it prints out each row in order within the while loop without having to go to the top of the loop.

Maybe I should use a while loop and the `continue` condition, so that every time $row[0] is echoed it returns the next row.

Comment: I assume this is a made-up example and you're not really using big constructed string-based queries like that any more?

Comment: If there's a better way of constructing the queries, I'd be interested in learning of a more optimal way? I'm somewhat of a newbie.

Comment: You should be using PDO and prepared statements. They help to prevent all sort of MASSIVE security issues and reliability problems. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: @Cylindric - I'm aware of prepared statements. It's on my list of things to learn. Any other advice? Thanks

Comment: Nothing specific - you're on the right track by being here asking sensible and well-written questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution which may not be optimal but it performs as required:

**Solution**

```
    $sql= mysql_query("select count(*), shop_order_action from shop_orders o
                  WHERE shop_order_action IN ('Sale', 'Transfer', 'Delivery', 'Return')
                  AND shop_order_day = '".$d."' AND shop_order_month = '".$m."' AND shop_order_year = '".$y."'
                  AND shop_order_location = 'Bawtry'
                  GROUP BY FIELD (shop_order_action, 'Sale', 'Transfer', 'Delivery', 'Return')");


while ($result=mysql_fetch_row($sql)) {

  if ($result[1] == 'Sale') { $sale = $result[0]; } 
  if ($result[1] == 'Transfer') { $transfer = $result[0]; } 
  if ($result[1] == 'Delivery') { $delivery = $result[0]; } 
  if ($result[1] == 'Return') { $return = $result[0]; } 

}
  if (isset($sale)) { echo $sale; }
  echo '<br />';
  if (isset($transfer)) { echo $transfer; }
  echo '<br />';

  etc ...
```

The code within the while loop stores each action value as a variable which can be called outside of the loop.